# How to cut a list into a second list with items that start with the same letter

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have this list: ['ants', 'apple', 'cake', 'can', 'cat', 'crop', 'long', 'poet', 'short', 'toe']
And I want to make a secondary list that consists of words that start with the same letter.

For example:
"c" -> letter_list = ['cake', 'can', 'cat', 'crop']

Any way I can do this in Python ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```py
word_list = ['cat','cod','cap','cad','car','bat','beat','bot','dog','dash','dig']
c_list = [i for i in word_list if i[0].lower() == 'c']
```

Result:

```
['cat', 'cod', 'cap', 'cad', 'car']
```

Edit:

Per your question about list comprehension, above is equivalent to:

```py
c_list = []
for word in word_list: # loops through words in word_list
    if word[0].lower() == 'c': # gets the first letter of a word and checks to see if it is equal to 'c'
        c_list.append(word) # adds word to our new list of c words if it starts with a 'c'.
```

List comprehension is a more pythonic and efficient alternative to for loops, when you want to perform some function on each list item or a subset of them.

For more information about list comprehension, please refer to a guide like [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please explain what that line does ? I'm a beginner and I don't really understand haha.

Comment: @RoeeArgaman added more information on list comprehension to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

The groupby() function from itertools works well for grouping stuff.  You can use it to form a dictionary of word lists keyed on the first letter:

```
words = ['ants', 'apple', 'cake', 'can', 'cat', 'crop', 'long', 
         'poet', 'short', 'toe']

from itertools import groupby

byLetter = { c:list(w) for c,w in groupby(sorted(words),lambda w:w[:1]) }

print(byLetter)
{'a': ['ants', 'apple'], 'c': ['cake', 'can', 'cat', 'crop'], 
 'l': ['long'], 'p': ['poet'], 's': ['short'], 't': ['toe']}

print(byLetter['c'])
['cake', 'can', 'cat', 'crop']

print(list(byLetter.values()))
[['ants', 'apple'], ['cake', 'can', 'cat', 'crop'], 
 ['long'], ['poet'], ['short'], ['toe']]
```